# First post not "no action needed" but already has a pending edit

Tags: support, review-queues, first-post-review

I recognize that it is a bug / error that it doesn't alert the user that there is a pending edit and that that particular aspect of this problem has been discussed many times before.

However, I was wondering what I should do with these in my queue? Are they "no action needed" because someone else has already edited it? Should I just skip the thing because there is nothing to do?

Comment: Perhaps a good idea would be to exclude posts with pending suggested edits from the FP and LA queues. (We already exclude users who've run out of daily votes from the queue.)

Comment: A pending edit is not an edit yet and may never actually become one. When there is a pending edit then that is a big clue that "no action needed" is not the right choice, editing may be needed. That doesn't answer what to do; to not get a head ache I would probably skip the review and then review the edit. Skip is always a valid option.

Comment: @Gimby that's normally what I do, but I always feel like its not optimal. As I was typing it out, doing no action needed felt like the right choice just because there isn't an action needed by you if it is already in the process of editing. My two cents at least.

Comment: Well, the issue with "no action needed" is, that this kicks the question out of the review queue. When then the suggested review gets rejected for some reasons, then the issue still remain in the question. Thus I would go with Gimby and skip this particular review, but then review the suggested edit, instead. This isn't an option for you, Ryan, because you currently don't have the necessary 2000 reputation points to perform edit reviews.

Comment: Bottom line: when in doubt, skip it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I recognize that it is a bug / error that it doesn't alert the user that there is a pending edit

Yes, this is most definitely a bug. The review queue *should* be detecting that there is a pending edit on the post, and *implicitly* skipping that review for users who do not have privileges to approve suggested edits.

> However, I was wondering what I should do with these in my queue?

In the meantime, **to work around the bug, you should "Skip" them**.

> Are they "no action needed" because someone else has already edited it?

Absolutely not. You have no guarantee that the other person's suggested edit is sufficient to fix all the problems with the post, and, even worse, you have no guarantee that the pending suggested edit is even going to get approved.

Action is definitely needed, and until that action is taken, action is *still needed*.

> Should I just skip the thing because there is nothing to do?

No, you should skip it because there is nothing that *you* can do *currently*.

If you run out of stuff to do, you can always return to your skipped reviews later and see if the edit has been approved.