# First post with pending edit still shows up

Tags: bug, review-queues, first-post-review

As asked in [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380717/first-post-not-no-action-needed-but-already-has-a-pending-edit) almost 2 years ago, I am still having this problem now. Review queue for first posts is still showing me posts with pending edits and since I have not enough privileges, I can only skip it. See example:

[image: review with pending edit]

Is this to be solved? It is not like this happened first time to me. Such posts should not be shown to unprivileged users as they can do nothing to improve them.

Comment: ok, you skip and where is the problem? Aren't there enough other reviews?

Comment: The problem is I and others invest time to read the post, identify problems and then find out can do nothing, could have reviewed another post meanwhile.